# Uninstall application via Windows GPO

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, domain-controller

The company I work at is switching the applications they use in Operations due to a recent upgrade in hardware equipment.  All user PCs at my office have what we will call Application 1 installed.  This application is installed at the same location on all PCs.  It was NOT installed via a GPO, but was installed manually while the computer was being set up for the user.

To avoid going around to each user station, I was curious if there was a way to uninstall a specific application at a specific location using a GPO.

We are planning to replace Application 1 with Application 2 at some point, but they cannot coincide on the same PC at the same time.  Therefore I will need to uninstall Application 1 first.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If the application wasn't installed with Group Policy then it can't be uninstalled with Group Policy... unless you can script the uninstall and set that script as a startup or logon script.

Comment: After a good bit of research, that looks like the approach we will have to take.  I was just curious if there were any additional options without having to write a custom script.  

We can uninstall the old application via a logon script and install the new application via a GPO software package.  Thank you, I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the application. Sometimes, if the application is possible to install via GPO, the deployed MSI installer will replace the version installed using other methods. In this case, it's possible to remove the application by first installing it. (*Like Shutdown button under Start menu.*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to uninstall the software, or use the tool to speed up the process.

PowerShell

$computerNames = @("ComputerName1", "rName2", "rName3")
$appName = "AnyDesk"
$yourAccount = Get-Credential
ForEach ($computerName in $computerNames) {
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $yourAccount -ScriptBlock {
Get-WmiObject Win32_product | Where {$*.name -eq $appName} | ForEach {
$*.Uninstall()
}
}
}

there are many of these scripts. The problem is debugging them.

tools:
Direct link to the article:
https://www.silentinstall.org/uninstall-gpo/
Briefly, the tool records the actions to uninstall an application and packages them into an msi file.